# How to change UI text depending on language settings Blender Python

Tags: python, add-on

I wan't my addon to be on multiple languages, how could I do it? taking for example a label

```
layout.label (text = 'use')
```

if the user has configured his blender in japanese I would like a japanese version to appear on the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to add anything, the `layout.label` function has a default `translate` argument that's `True`. It will automatically fetch the translation from the builtin dictionary.

[Link to the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.label)

[image]

Of course, provided the word has been added to the dictionary in the target language.

Here's the result of

`layout.label(text="Use")`

[image]

Comment: [Source/Interface/Internationalization](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Source/Interface/Internationalization) has specifics on the rare cases where you do have to deal with it as well as an explanation for how to do it.